# Get type of elements in list clojure

Tags: types, clojure, quote

I have a quoted expression e.g.

```
(def foo '(+ 1 (bar)))
```

I want to be able to find the type of any element of this list, e.g. to do something like

```
(type (second foo))
```

I get different results depending on the type of value, for example the following both evaluate to java.lang.Double, which is what I would want

```
(type '3.0)
(type 3.0)
```

Yet

```
(type '+)
(type +)
```

yields respectively

```
clojure.lang.Symbol
clojure.core$_PLUS_
```

I thought perhaps the resolve key would help yet

```
(type (resolve '+))
```

evaluates to:

clojure.lang.Var

Comment: Oops! Fixed, still the value out of (type (resolve '+)) is clojure.lang.Var.  How can I get from this to clojure.core$_PLUS_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just symbols `'+`, `'bar` and self-evaluating object `1` (long) in your list

```
(= '(+ 1 (bar))
   (list '+ '1 (list 'bar)))
=> true
```

Use `eval`.

```
(type (eval '+)) 
=> clojure.core$_PLUS_
```

And

```
(type '3.0) = (type 3.0) = (type (eval '3.0)) = java.lang.Double
```

because numbers are self-evaluating objects.

Answer (score 0):

Dereference the resolved Var:

```
(type (deref (resolve '+)))
```